# How can I click svg line tag having more boundaries?

Tags: javascript, html, web, svg, frontend

I'm every day thanks to answering developer.
How can I click svg line tag having more boundaries?

This is my line tag.
[image]

This is I want click ling tag boundary.
[image]

```html
  <body>
    <svg height="210" width="500">
      <defs>
        <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0" width="200%" height="200%">
          <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceGraphic" dx="2" dy="2" />
          <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="offOut" mode="normal" />
        </filter>
      </defs>
      <line
        x1="0"
        y1="0"
        x2="200"
        y2="200"
        style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:5;box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px red;"
      ></line>
    </svg>
  </body>
  <script>
    document
      .getElementsByTagName("line")[0]
      .addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        console.log("lineClick", e);
      });
  </script>
```

How Can I click event boundary set more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a second wider invisible line on top of the first, capture its clicks and dispatch them to the visible line underneath.

```html
  <body>
    <svg height="210" width="500">
      <defs>
        <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0" width="200%" height="200%">
          <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceGraphic" dx="2" dy="2" />
          <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="offOut" mode="normal" />
        </filter>
      </defs>
      <line
        x1="0"
        y1="0"
        x2="200"
        y2="200"
        style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:5;box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px red;"
      ></line>
      <line onclick="document
      .getElementsByTagName('line')[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));"
        x1="0"
        y1="0"
        x2="200"
        y2="200"
        style="stroke:none;stroke-width:40;pointer-events:all;cursor:pointer"
      ></line>
      </svg>
  </body>
  <script>
    document
      .getElementsByTagName("line")[0]
      .addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        console.log("lineClick", e);
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks.  But I can't make another element. So, I'm used javascript + Linear function.